# Multiple windows of the same SwiftUI (mac) app share the same state

Tags: swift, swiftui

so this is basically a Hail Mary, but I'm really out of ideas as to what could be causing this:
I have a small mac-app that uses the default `WindowGroup`, which according to the documentation ensures that.

> "Each window created by the group maintains an independent state. For example, for each new window created from the group, new memory is allocated for any `State` or `StateObject` variables instantiated by the scene's view hierarchy."

Nevertheless, the `NavigationView` shows the same selected list across all windows. Put differently, `selectedLabel` shares and updates across multiple windows, even tho in my humble understanding this is not supposed to happen.

Another problem, which I don't know if it's related, is that both `windowStyle` and `windowToolbarStyle` set on this `WindowGroup` are ignored.

It may be a minor issue, but I'm really stuck here, so any help would be appreciated!

My MainApp (simplified):

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MainApp: App {
    @State private var selectedLabel: ViewModel? = .init()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SidebarView(selectedLabel: $selectedLabel)
        }
        .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
        .windowToolbarStyle(UnifiedCompactWindowToolbarStyle())
    }
}
```

My Sidebar (also simplified):

```swift
import SFSafeSymbols
import SwiftUI

struct SidebarView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SidebarViewModel()
    @Binding var selectedLabel: ViewModel?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.createStockList()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemSymbol: .plus)
                })
                
                List(viewModel.stockLists, id: \.id) { stockList in
                    NavigationLink(destination: StockListView(viewModel: stockList),
                                   tag: stockList,
                                   selection: $selectedLabel) {
                            Text(stockList.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're storing your `selectedLabel` at the `WindowGroup` level and passing it to each sidebar. You should store that state in the `SidebarView` if you want it to be different.

Comment: @jnpdx Jesus, that worked.
Thank you so much, you're my hero!

Comment: Great -- added it as an answer that you can accept with the green checkmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're storing your `selectedLabel` at the `WindowGroup` level and passing it to each sidebar. You should store that state in the `SidebarView` if you want it to be different.